# Строка равная null запишется в память устройства?

Tags: java, android

Не делаю проверку строки перед записью в файл и хоть она и null, запись производится. Потом я загружаю эту строку , загруженную переменную проверяю на null и она оказывается не null. Что произошло? в файл записались какие то данные, о том что этот объект null и теперь они считываются в виде строки?

Comment: Так в память или в файл?

Comment: В файл. Исправил в вопросе.

Comment: я загружаю файл в из памяти в переменную, проверяю null ли (перед записью  в память он был null) и теперь он не null. Печатаю в лог , что в нем есть. Но в нем ни одного пробела даже нет.

Comment: Всё зависит от способа записи и чтения - без кода сказать сложно почему именно так у Вас получается

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Текстовый файл содержит текст. `null` - это не текст. При записи `null` в файл, вероятно, записывается либо пустая строка, либо строка со словом `"null"`.

https://ideone.com/cStgv3

```
class Ideone {
  public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception {
    System.out.println("Line 1");
    System.out.println((String)null);
    System.out.println("Line 3");
    System.out.println("");
    System.out.println("Line 5");
    System.out.println("null");
    System.out.println("Line 7");
  }
}
```

```
Line 1
null
Line 3

Line 5
null
Line 7
```

Comment: вот мой комментарий к вопросу. Повторюсь. Строка перед записью null. Теперь я ее загружаю и она не null. Печатаю и не распечатывается ничего . Пустота. Даже пробела нет

Comment: Пустая строка - это и есть пустота. Пустая строка на заканчивается переводом строки. Тот логгер, который ты используешь, не считает нужным что-то выводить, если получает на вход null. Это в некоторой степени логично.

Comment: Уточните пожалуйста, пустая строка чем заканчивается или начинается?

Comment: Пустая строка - эта такая, у которой длина 0 символов. Она ничем не заканчивается и не начинается, т. к. она пустая.

Comment: и теперь переменная, в которой такая пустая строка, будет не null , т.к. в ней пустая строка?

Comment: @Turalllb скорее всего да, из пула строк она возьмет строку "" (в случае JDK 8)